# Create Class From Hybrid Interface Type

Tags: interface, typescript

First of all, I'm very new to TS, and during my reading in 
http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook I stop at trying to understand how Hybrid Types Interface works.

In the example of the TS:

```
interface ICounter {
    (start: number): string;
    interval: number;
    reset(): void;
}
var c: ICounter;
c(10);
c.reset();
c.interval = 5.0;
```

So, the problem was when I tried to write a class using this interface, the problem was the line:

```
(start: number): string;
```

First I thought that this line represents a function so tried to create:

```
class Test implements ICounter {
    interval: number;

    reset(): void { }

    start(start: number): string {
        return "";
    }
}
```

But this keep showing that "Types Test and ICounter have incompatible signatures", so what I'm missing here? I thought that interfaces should work the same way for classes and variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ICounter` represents a function that has two properties—`interval` and `reset`.

This line in the interface...

```
(start: number): string;
```

...describes a way to call the function. It's shown in the example as:

```
c(10)
```

The other lines describe the function's properties—`interval` and `reset`.

```
c.reset();
c.interval = 5.0;
```

As stated in the handbook, this is used for representing JavaScript libraries that do this. So for example, the above could represent the following JavaScript code:

```
function counter(start) {
    alert(start);
    return "some string";
}

counter.reset = function() { alert('reset called'); };
counter.interval = 1;
```

In addition to all this, note that the class you described could be represented by the following interface:

```
interface ITest {
    interval: number;
    reset: () => void;
    start: (start: number) => string;
}
```

Comment: tks David, this solve my doubt (I think), I was initially think that interfaces should be always implemented by anything.

Answer (score 0):

`class` implies that you will create instances via `new` operator. `new` creates `object`, not `function`, so it is impossible to implement class, which instances can called as function. You can do something like this:

```
interface ICounterObject {
    interval: number;
    reset(): void;
}

interface ICounter extends ICounterObject {
    (start: number): string;
    __proto__: ICounterObject;
}

class Test implements ICounterObject {
    static createCounter(): ICounter {
        var counter = <ICounter>function (start: number): string {
            return "";
        };
        counter.__proto__ = Test.prototype;
        return counter;
    }

    interval: number;

    reset(): void { }
}
```

Note, [__proto__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) is from ES6, but de-facto is supported in ES5 browsers. If you want to use function prototype members (e.g `call` and `apply`) mix prototypes:

```
function mixWithFunc<T extends Function>(obj: { __proto__?}, func: T) {
    var objProto = <{ constructor }>obj.__proto__;
    var objClass = <{ __mixedProto__ }>objProto.constructor;
    var proto = <typeof obj>objClass.__mixedProto__;
    if (!proto) {
        proto = {};
        proto.__proto__ = objProto;
        ['call', 'apply', 'bind'].forEach(p => proto[p] = Function.prototype[p]);
        objClass.__mixedProto__ = proto;
    }
    (<typeof obj>func).__proto__ = proto;
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(p => func[p] = obj[p]);
    return func;
}

interface ICounter extends Counter {
    (start: number): string;
}

class Counter {
    static create() {
        var self: ICounter = mixWithFunc(
            new Counter(),
            <ICounter>function (start: number) {
                return "started with interval: " + self.interval;
            });
        return self;
    }

    interval = 1000;

    reset() { this.interval = 0; }
}
```

Of course you can just add members to each instance of your function instead of prototyping.

Comment: I mark David as an answer but ur explanation was awesome, but I can just vote for 1 solution, tks @Artem ! I don't understand so well es6 (or typescript) but I will study more to fully understand your second part of answer.